# Validate number from id card from all countries

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

anyone knows any function or regular expression to validate the id number of id card from all countries?

I found this regular expression, who validates  id number from Spain but i need validate all id number from all countries.

```
^((([A-Z]|[a-z])\d{8})|(\d{8}([A-Z]|[a-z])))$
```

Thanks.

Comment: You'll be hard pushed to find a single universal regexp that will work with all id numbers from every country in the world.... id numbers aren't a universal constant

Comment: No way of doing it without knowing where the ID card is supposed to be from.

Comment: What about countries without ID cards, such as the UK?

Comment: @gbn - technically, the UK does have ID cards, but as they're optional?!? and you have to pay a large sum of money for the privilege of having one, and can't actually use it for anything... a bit pointless really

Comment: Do you really mean validate (checking internal checksums of ID numbers) or just check if it fits in a certain format?

Comment: @dgw just check if it fits in a certain format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot validate id numbers from all countries by one regular expressions becouse each country has a different policy for example in my country it is validated by `^\\d{14}$` a.e., 14 numbers.

What you can do is associate each country with a regex pattern and validate the id depending on its country.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's possible as the format and the validation rule is different for different countries.